# Using reflection, can I list fields in a #region?

Tags: c#

Using reflection, can I list fields in a `#region` ?

Otherwise, can you think of other ways to achieve "grouping" of fields on a class to enumerate them ? Tagging all of the fields with an attribute is not an option as this is actually what I would like to get off.

Comment: `#region` is a pre processor directive. It does not get compiled. Therefore you cannot use reflection. maybe using the VS api to examine the .cs file?

Comment: Why can't you tag the fields with an attribute?  Fields can have multiple attributes.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to group some fields, they probably belong into their own class.

Refactor your code accordingly and you can easily enumerate the fields in each group, because each group now has its own class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible because regions are Preprocessor directives and do not get compiled.

Maybe you should include a sample of what you want to achieve. I think there would be a better solution than using regions.
What about using one class per region and create a property?

Answer (score -1):

Jerome, I thought I'd revive your question as I have the same requirement.

In my specific case I was thinking of using regions as an interface to serialisation. At present I'm using attributes, but like you would like to offer alternatives, syntactical sugar in the form of grouping as it were.

Two solutions that may suffice:
1) T4 Templates to generate partial class logic that adds the necessary attributes. In other words the T4 holds the grouping logic. It's likely too ugly to merit any serious consideration.

2) Pre-build events that alter the code to ensure that region grouped members are tagged with the necessary attributes. This is a part way compromise.

Would be very interested in hearing of any pre-build region manipulation techniques.

In response to the idea of sub-classes this is not a great option as it either adds complexity to the contract interface or it means creating extra properties to access these forced sub-classes.

Comment: You should consider posting a new question as this is not a direct answer to the question. It's a response/new question

Comment: I don't see this is a separate question. Forkbeard did propose two nice solutions (using `T4 template` and `Pre-Build event`) to the question

Comment: Many thanks to Neverever for quite rightly pointing out that I was indeed proposing two solutions to the exact question being asked. Utter madness that I should be down voted because some reader cannot understand the post ;)